# How to keep the value of a variable pushed several times in the same list?

Tags: javascript, list, variables

Here is my problem : I've got a function in which I have a variable whose value keeps changing every time I call this function. Later in the code of the function, I push the variable in a list. But when I do it several times, the variables are stacking well but all the values take the same as the new one.

```
var new_plane; //I define these variables here because I want to use it again in other functions
var list_plane = [];

var Planes = { //I define the object
    number: "",
    airline: ""
};

function add_plane() {
    new_plane = Planes;
    new_plane.number = 10; //Random number
    new_plane.airline = "Air France"; //Random airline of a list

    list_plane.push(new_plane); //I push the variable in the list

    for (let i = 0; i < list_plane.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += list_plane[i].number + " " + list_plane[i].airline + "<br />"; //The body is used for the example and the output too
    };
};
```

When the first plane is entered, everything is fine. But when the second plane is set, the two planes have the same values, and not their own values as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
var Planes = { //I define the object
    number: "",
    airline: ""
};
```

inside of the function, because otherwise you have the same object reference for each element in the array.

---

An other solution could be to use the `Plane` pattern as template for a new object

```
// global
var Planes = {
        number: "",
        airline: ""
    };

function add_plane() {
    var new_plane = Object.assign({}, Planes); // get copy

    new_plane.number = 10;
    new_plane.airline = "Air France";

    list_plane.push(new_plane);

    for (let i = 0; i < list_plane.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += list_plane[i].number + " " + list_plane[i].airline + "<br />";
    } // no semicolon here
} // no semicolon here
```

Comment: Changing the declaration of Planes to be OOP would be much more common.

Comment: @computercarguy, right, if this concept is taken, but other concepts works as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `new_plane` refers to the same object and you push it multiple times into the array.

You may want to initialize a new object each time like this:

```
function add_plane() {
  const new_plane = {
    number: 10,
    airline: "Air France"
  };

  list_plane.push(new_plane);

  //...
}
```

However I would suggest passing the array as an argument to the add_plane function or even better use OOP.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many references to have to that object (even within the same array), overall you still have only one object.  And you're updating the properties on that object.

Instead, define a new object to be inserted into the array:

```
function add_plane() {
    let new_plane = {
        number: 10, //Random number
        airline: "Air France" //Random airline of a list
    };

    list_plane.push(new_plane); //I push the variable in the list

    for (let i = 0; i < list_plane.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += list_plane[i].number + " " + list_plane[i].airline + "<br />"; //The body is used for the example and the output too
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to create a new instance of Planes: new_plane = new Planes();

What you currently have is a single object declared, Planes, and you keep updating the vale of that one instance. Whether you add it to the list_plane or not, any other use of that object will be updated.

Edit:
You will also want to change your declaration to:

```
function Planes () { //I define the object
    number = "";
    airline = "";
}
```

This is how you make your code OOP.  I missed the difference earlier, sorry about that.

Comment: No, I can't because it tells me that Planes can't be used as this kind of object

Answer (score 0):

```js
var list_plane = [];

var Planes = function (n, a) { //I define the object
    this.number = n;
    this.airline = a;
};

function add_plane(num, air) {
    list_plane.push(new Planes(num, air)); //I push the variable in the list
}

function printAirplanes () {
    for (let i = 0; i < list_plane.length; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += list_plane[i].number + " " + list_plane[i].airline + "<br />"; //The body is used for the example and the output too
    };
};

add_plane(10, "Air france");
add_plane(15, "KLM");

printAirplanes();
```

From a development perspective I think this is cleaner. One important thing: I think you should take out the for loop from the method that adds.

This can also be re-writen for ES2015 and others but I guess this can be homework for another time.